# MongoDB aggregate with sum and minimum treshhold

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I show only results with count > 10?

```
db.mydate.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : "Ident.url",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Something like `{$match:{count:{$gt:10}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `match` to filter the count:

```
db.mydate.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : "Ident.url",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      {
        $match : {
          count: {
            $gt: 10
          }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter with $match after group

```
 db.mydate.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : "Ident.url",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      {$match: {count: {$gt:10}}}
   ]
)
```